# Show validation error when texboxes are empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio, validation

```
        double HP, L, hr, Est, eee, result;
        string output;
        HP = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        L = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        hr = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        Est = double.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        eee = double.Parse(textBox5.Text);

        result = HP * (L / 100) * 0.746 * hr * (((1 / Est) - (1 / eee)) * 100);
        output = " " + result;

        textBox6.Text = output;
```

I want to show a validation message when one or more textboxes are blank.

Comment: What do you mean by "incomplete" ? When a field (textBoxX) is empty ?

Comment: Based on the OPs comment, the question is about adding input validation to textboxes, so I've reworded the question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the fields isn't empty :

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(...)){

}
```

Check is the value is a valid double :

```
double parsedValue;

if (!double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out parsedValue))
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is a double only field");
    return;
}
```

---

You would get something like that :

```
if(nullorempty tests){
    if(youcanparse first textbox){
        the value of that textbox is not valid
    } else if(youcanparse second textbox){
         ...
    }
} else {
   show "you must enter something !"
}
```

And so on

Comment: @Uit14bs This should do the trick, come back if you got another problem ! :)

Comment: @Alexender Beaudet It is the game of understanding question

Comment: @Alexandre Beaudet   i use   String.IsNullOrEmpty   textBox1_TextChanged   it code                                                                                                              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
                return;

            double HP;
            if (!double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out HP))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("invalid value");
                textBox1.Clear();
            }